# Add new fields to table with migration on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

When I add new fields to table with migration on codeigniter, all records deleted on table. How can i keep old recors on my table with migration? 
Thank you.

Comment: I changed $config['migration_version'] and added fields on database file in migration folder.

Comment: I have never used migration for codeigniter but it seems it applies a `DROP` to the table when migrating. You have to find a way to just `ALTER` it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `add_column` rather than `add_field`. `add_field` is used to define fields for table creation, `add_column` modifies an existing table. The [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html) are pretty confusing on that point.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. You can try this -

```
$this->load->database();    
$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name TEXT NULL");
```